# How to make sure one method can be bound only once to an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Below code is Just for Demo.

### Html

```
<div>
<a href='javascript:' id="foo">Foo</a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="target"></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#foo').bind('click', write);
    jQuery('#foo').bind('click', write);
    jQuery('#foo').bind('click', write);
    jQuery('#foo').bind('click', write);

   /*
      although  I am binding click event four times with same METHOD
      I want jQuery to bind it only once and ignore rest request to bind the 
      same function
  */
});
function write() {
    jQuery('#target').append('modified<br>');
}
```

In JavaScript I am binding same function four times to a link using jQuery, But is there any way that jQuery processes only first request and ignores other request to bind same event.

[Demo : using jQuery1.7.1](http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Y7/)

[Demo : using jQuery1.3.2](http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Y7/4/) (I am getting expected behavior, but I want this behavior with jQuery1.7.1)

Comment: And which click handler should it keep? The first or the last?

Comment: Why would you bind the same thing *four times* to a click event?

Comment: it should bind same methods only once. Eg in my case i am binding same methods 4 times, i am expecting it to bind it only once. See the demo i have added with jQuery(1.3.2)

Comment: This sounds as if you have an architectural problem somewhere else in your code. You should focus on binding the same thing only once, instead of trying to make duplicate bindings harmless.

Comment: Agreed, Tomalak. Multiple bindings firing multiple times is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @ChessWhiz  look a these demos http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Y7/  and http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Y7/2/   : with jquery1.3.2 its binding only once each function, with jQuery1.7.1: its binding same function multiple times. I dont know y.

Comment: @Tomalak: please read above comment.

Comment: @RusiNova You've already linked to these code samples in your question. They do not explain why you're binding the same thing multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid binding the event handler four times in the first place.

If you can't, I suggest you to unbind previous event handlers first (jQuery 1.7 syntax):

```
jQuery('#foo').off('click', write).on('click', write);
```

You could also use namespaced events:

```
jQuery('#foo').off('click.write').on('click.write', write);
```

Anything else is fighting the symptoms of your problem, not the cause. -

---

Regarding the different behaviour in jQuery 1.3 and jQuery 1.7:

> As of jQuery 1.4.2 duplicate event handlers can be bound to an element instead of being discarded. This is useful when the event data feature is being used, or when other unique data resides in a closure around the event handler function.

Comment: Yes i was thinking the same thing. I would appreciate you comment on why this worked with jQuery1.3.2 and didnt worked with jQuery 1.4.2 or higher. Is it an added figure or a bug??. U may check these demos http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Y7/   http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Y7/4

Comment: @Rusi: I don't know whether it was a bug or not. It might have been a feature first and was then considered to be a bug. The documentation simply states: *"As of jQuery 1.4.2 duplicate event handlers can be bound to an element instead of being discarded. This is useful when the event data feature is being used, or when other unique data resides in a closure around the event handler function."*.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, the first function call will prevent the others from firing. See http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

```
function write(event) {
    jQuery('#target').append('modified<br>');
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

For an example, see http://jsfiddle.net/RareZ/2

NOTE: You don't want to use `return false` for this purpose. See http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: Uhm... it only appends the text once because your code throws the error *"Uncaught ReferenceError: stopPropagation is not defined"* and stops execution.  You can change the method name to `foo` and you get the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/RareZ/1/

Comment: there is a catch its not allowing other methods to bound to be triggered with this, while in jQuery 1.3.2 it worked perfectly. see demos   http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Y7/2/   http://jsfiddle.net/7J3Y7/3/

Comment: i only want to prevent the SAME function to be prevented from getting called, while if i do `stopImmediatePropagation()` it will stop invoking all bound functions (even if they are not same)

Comment: @RusiNova Sorry, didn't fully understand the question. For that behavior, you should go with Felix's answer.

Answer (score 0):

`.stopImmediatePropagation()` will stop any more event handlers from firing for the same event.

```
function write(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    jQuery('#target').append('modified<br>');
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gwZSC/

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation

Comment: I haven't used `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` before so to better understand the function I would like to know what the down-vote is for. Thanks.

Comment: @RusiNova My code doesn't throw any errors. The reason Felix commented that is because CheeseWhiz called the `stopPropagation()` function on nothing (source: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/RareZ/), it has to be called on an event object like this: `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a native API method to do so, but you could certainly create a helper that would check if an event handler exists before binding:

```
// selector - The jQuery selector for the elements you wish to bind
// event    - The name of the event you wish to bind (e.g. 'click')
// handler  - The function you wish to bind the the event
function (selector, event, handler) {
    var elements = $(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (!$.data(elements.get(i), 'events')[event])
            elements[i].bind(event, handler);
    }

    // Alternative implementation
    // $.each($(selector), function (i, element) {
    //     if (element.data('events')[event])
    //         element.bind(event, handler);
    // });
}
```

I may recommend rewriting this as a jQuery plugin if necessary.